# Rank elements in nested list without sorting list

Tags: python, list

Let's say I have a nested list:

```
list = [[10, 2, 8, 4], [12, 6, 4, 1], [8, 4, 3, 2], [9, 3, 4, 6]]
```

I want to rank the elements in the sublist against each other to create a new nested list with the rankings.

```
result = [[1, 4, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 4, 3, 2]]
```

in the first sublist 10 would be 1st, 8 2nd, etc.

Comment: I'd love to see your attempts. If you don't know where to start, look at `numpy` `argsort`

Comment: From highest to lowest, that is?

Comment: What do you mean by "without sorting list"?

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Answer (score 2):

There are already some good solutions. Here just another one - functional approach for reference:

No 3rd library used.

```
lst = # your lists      - don't use builtin "list"

def ranking(nums):
    ranks = {x:i for i, x in enumerate(sorted(nums, reverse=True),1)}
    return [ranks[x] for x in nums] # quick mapping back: O(1)
```

Calling it:

```
result = list(map(ranking, lst))
```

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the comment, you can use `numpy.argsort`, using it twice gives you the rank for the values, which need to be subtracted from `len` of the sub list to rank from highest to lowest, you can use List-Comprehension to do it for all the sub lists.

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> lst = [[10, 2, 8, 4], [12, 6, 4, 1], [8, 4, 3, 2], [9, 3, 4, 6]]
>>> [(len(sub)-np.argsort(sub).argsort()).tolist() for sub in lst]
[[1, 4, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 4, 3, 2]]
```

You can even use 2D numpy array and negate the values, then directly call `argsort` twice on the resulting array, and finally add 1:

```py
>>> (-np.array(lst)).argsort().argsort()+1

array([[1, 4, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 4, 3, 2]], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`scipy.stats.rankdata`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rankdata.html):

```
my_list = [[10, 2, 8, 4], [12, 6, 4, 1], [8, 4, 3, 2], [9, 3, 4, 6]]


from scipy.stats import rankdata
[list(len(l)+1-rankdata(l).astype(int)) for l in my_list]
```

output:

```
[[1, 4, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 4, 3, 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Without `numpy`/`scipy`:

```
[[sorted(li, reverse=True).index(x)+1 for x in li] for li in data]
```

---

```
[[1, 4, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 4, 3, 2]]
```

Comment: This is highly inefficient, you sort the list for each item, and the search of index needs to read the list again. This is really not a way to go IMO ;)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with no external libraries, and with a better time complexity, just in case your sublists are a bit longer than 4 items (this has some overhead but I presume it is O(n log n) because of the call to `sorted`).

```
def rank_all(ls):
    result = []
    for subls in ls:
        pairs = sorted([(subls[j],j) for j in range(len(subls))], reverse=True)
        ranked = [0] * len(subls)
        for j,p in enumerate(pairs):
            ranked[p[1]]=j+1
        result.append(ranked)
    return result
```

Comment: For `pairs`, you don't need an additional intermediate list, and you can use `enumerate` there too: `((x, j) for j, x in enumerate(subls))`